# Rails 3 + Transactions: how do they work?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, transactions

I have this code, as you can see i have two params. And i in the one table I create new fields, in another table I updated fields.

I need to paste them into MySQL. Everything is cool, but i have a question: how to do a transaction because i don't want to paste in database only one of them (update or create). Because now, if I filled one params, the table is created ot updated, but I want to put them ALL in database at ONCE. So my question is... how to do transaction to avoid pasting one of them?

```
json_grid_params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:grid_json]) 
json_form_params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:form_json])  

   json_grid_params.each do |json_grid_params|   
    report      = Report.find(:all, :conditions => ["wat_id in (?)", json_grid_params["wat_id"].to_i])

        report.each do |r|
            rr = r.update_attributes(:percent_money => json_grid_params["percent_money"],
                                     :percent_item  => json_grid_params["percent_item"], 
                                     :trend         => json_grid_params["trend"])
        end

        form = FormAnswer.create(json_form_params)
```

updated:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    json_grid_params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:grid_json])
    json_form_params = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:form_json])  
           json_grid_params.each do |json_grid_params|   
        report = Report.find(:all, :conditions => ["wat_id in (?)", json_grid_params["wat_id"].to_i])
            report.each do |r|
                rr = r.update_attributes(:percent_money => json_grid_params["percent_money"], 
                          :percent_item  => json_grid_params["percent_item"], 
                          :trend         => json_grid_params["trend"])
            rr.save!
            form = FormAnswer.create(json_form_params)
            #form.save!
            end
        end 
end
```

and in log have this error : (If i leave grid_params empty)

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `save!' for true:TrueClass):
  app/components/report_grid.rb:122:in `block (4 levels) in <class:ReportGrid>'
  app/components/report_grid.rb:118:in `each'
  app/components/report_grid.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in <class:ReportGrid>'
  app/components/report_grid.rb:116:in `each'
  app/components/report_grid.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ReportGrid>'
  app/components/report_grid.rb:113:in `block in <class:ReportGrid>'

Rendered /home/parallels/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails314/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered /home/parallels/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails314/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /home/parallels/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails314/gems/actionpack-3.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (2.8ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ...
end
```

will wrap the block in a transaction. If some of your models have different database connections, then call transaction on that specific class for the transaction to happen on the correct connection.

Comment: rr.update_attributes  saves it immediately, and returns true. you then try to save! on true, which is invalid.  See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes